# БД SQLite вывод в DBGrid

Tags: dbgrid, delphi, sqlite

В Delphi есть БД SQLite, и в нее произвожу запись/чтение через TSQLiteTable. Ни через ADO, ни другими путями не могу вывести в DBGrid (StringGrid работает).

Answer (score 2):

TSQLiteTable->TDataSource->DBGrid

Comment: Откуда вы взяли вот этот компонент "TSQLiteTable" ?

Comment: это уже компонента доступа к БД - либо DISQLite